# Do instance variables declared outside of `__init__()` have any differences in python?

Tags: python, class, variables, instance, declaration

I'm wondering weather it is necessary to define class instance variable within class declarations.

I tried assigning a new instance variable after the object (class instance) was already created, and looks like there is no difference. Are there any caveats in this approach?

```
class Context():
    def __init__(self, extension):
        self.extension = extension

c = Context('extension+')

print(f"before: {c.__dict__}")

c.new_var = 'new_var_content'
print(c.extension + c.new_var)

print(f"after: {c.__dict__}")
```

printed:

```
before: {'extension': 'extension+'}
extension+new_var_content
after: {'extension': 'extension+', 'new_var': 'new_var_content'}
```

Comment: It’s already been created in `__init__` too, so no, no difference between `extension` and `new_var`.

Comment: `c` is nothing but `self,` when you call an instance *method*. So doing `c.attribute` is an explicit way of doing `self.attribute`. Usually, you do every instance manipulation inside a method so that it can be re-used by all class instances.

Comment: If I rember correctly in C# or C++ this type of declartion is no allowed. However in Python it looks like OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between declaring `self.foo` within a `def __init__(self, <arguments>):` definition, and declaring it after an object has been instantiated.

Both assignments have instance-level scope.

Given -

```py
class Context:
    i_am_a_class_variable = 'class_string'
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar
```

See -

1. class attributes can be accessed without instantiating an object.

```
>>> Context.i_am_a_class_variable
'class_string'
```

2. instance attributes can be assigned during instantiation using the `__init__(self)` function.

```
>>> Context.bar
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-8be0704da5be> in <module>                                 
----> 1 Context.bar
>>> instance = Context('bar')
>>> instance.bar
'bar'
```

3. instance attributes can be assigned after instantiation, directly

```
>>> instance = Context('bar')
>>> instance.foo = 'foo'
>>> instance.foo
'foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

Speaking in terms of whether you can assign a value to the property or create a new property, there is no difference if you do it within **init** or anywhere else after the object is created as in both cases it gets added in **dict** of the object(unless you use **slots**)

However, if you want your class to be initialized with desired state (i.e, having some mandatory variables with default/preset values) , you should put it in **init**. Since **init** is called implicitly as soon as object is created, you object will be having desired state.